# Descombinar celdas de Excel desde C# con Gembox

Tags: c#, excel

¡Hola! Estoy realizando una automatización de un archivo de Excel con **C#** y la librería **Gembox**, he estado trabajando con un **.xlsx** que contiene rangos de celdas combinadas en las columnas A y B y **el objetivo es separarlos**.

Investigando y haciendo pruebas he podido encontrar la manera de separar algunos rangos pero, o solo el primero encontrado automáticamente o asignando las posiciones exactas de los mismos.
El problema es que la automatización consiste en varios .xlsx (uno a la vez) y  los rangos siempre son aleatorios, entonces necesito **implementar alguna técnica que los detecte automáticamente** de acuerdo al archivo trabajado. Agradecería muchísimo si pudieran orientarme al respecto.

```
//de esta manera se separa solo el primer rango combinado encontrado

var mergedRange = worksheet.Rows
                              .SelectMany(row1 => row1.AllocatedCells)
                              .Select(cell => cell.MergedRange)
                              .First(range => range != null);
                worksheet.Cells.GetSubrange(mergedRange.ToString()).Merged = false;

//y así, rangos en específico por medio de las posiciones

worksheet.Cells.GetSubrange("A9:A99").Merged = false;
worksheet.Cells.GetSubrange("A100:A105").Merged = false;
```

```
//sin incluir las secciones anteriores, el código para leer el excel es el siguiente

ExcelFile workbook = ExcelFile.Load(@"C:\archivo.xlsx");

            for (int sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < workbook.Worksheets.Count; sheetIndex++)
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[sheetIndex];

                for (int rowIndex = 7; rowIndex < worksheet.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
                {
                    ExcelRow row = worksheet.Rows[rowIndex];
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
            workbook.Save(@"C:\archivo_Transormado.xlsx");
```

De antemano, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola de nuevo!
Después de varios días de buscar solucionar el problema y al fin animarme a preguntar por aquí, he encontrado la manera de hacer la separación de rangos combinados y también de rellenar fila por fila dichas celdas con el dato que les correspondía al estar combinadas.
Soy algo nueva en esto, pero comparto el código esperando le pueda servir a alguien y por supuesto que se aceptan sugerencias :)

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");

        //carga del .xlsx
        ExcelFile workbook = ExcelFile.Load(@"C:\archivo.xlsx");
        
        //recorrido de hojas para situarse en la primera
        for (int sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < workbook.Worksheets.Count; sheetIndex++)
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[sheetIndex];

            //recorrido de celdas
            for (int rowIndex = 7; rowIndex < worksheet.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
            {
                //ciclo para encontrar todos los rangos de celdas combinadas y separarlos
                try
                {
                    var mergedRange = worksheet.Rows.SelectMany(row1 => row1.AllocatedCells)
                      .Select(cell1 => cell1.MergedRange).First(range => range != null);

                    worksheet.Cells.GetSubrange(mergedRange.ToString()).Merged = false;
                    //Console.WriteLine(mergedRange);
                }
                catch {  }

                //recorrido de celdas por columnas
                ExcelRow row = worksheet.Rows[rowIndex];
                for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < row.AllocatedCells.Count; columnIndex++)
                {
                    ExcelCell cell = row.Cells[columnIndex];

                    //validación de celdas vacías en las columnas A y B para rellenarlas con su dato previo correspondiente (de los rangos combinados a los que pertenecían)
                    if (worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 0].Value == null || worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1].Value == null)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex].Value = (worksheet.Cells[rowIndex - 1, columnIndex].Value);
                    }

                    Console.Write($" {cell.Value},");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
        //guarda el archivo ya transformado
        workbook.Save(@"C:\archivo_Transformado.xlsx");
    }
```